# What is wrong with this piece of code?

Tags: java

Not sure what is wrong with this code, why does it terminate?

```
public class task2 {
    public static void main (String args []){
        String str = "abc";
        str  = pad (str, 10, '*');
    }
    public static String pad(String base, int n, char c){
        while (base.length()<n ){
            base = base +c;
        }
        return base;
    }
}
```

Comment: Next time you ask a question about some code, explain _what you expect it to do_. Any code "terminates" sooner or later, that wasn't the issue in your case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code works fine, but you never print out the resulting String:

```
public static void main (String args []){
    String str = "abc";
    str  = pad (str, 10, '*');
    System.out.println(str);  // *** you need this
}
```

A side recommendation: rename the class to Task2. Java naming conventions dictate that class names should start with an uppercase letter while method and variable names with a lower case letter:

```
public class Task2 {
   public static void main(String args[]) {
      String str = "abc";
      str = pad(str, 10, '*');
      System.out.println(str);
   }

   public static String pad(String base, int n, char c) {
      while (base.length() < n) {
         base = base + c;
      }
      return base;
   }
}
```

This is important since by following convention, your code will be much more understandable by other Java coders and (most importantly) by your future self.

Comment: Recommendations that are not answering the question should be in comments, shouldn't they?

Comment: Yeah im such an idiot.. thank you

Comment: @Suseika: I think that this answers his likely problem with his code.